# How to manage a set of data filters on the frontend before querying the backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

I have a Vue app with an express backend that lets users manage lists of Movies, TV Shows, Books etc.

Users are able to filter and sort their libraries by a wide variety of options (release dates, critic scores, genres, etc)

I have an API endpoint that accepts filter and sort options but I'm struggling to come up with a scalable way to set, store, and manage filters on the frontend before sending them off the backend.

Currently I store the filter settings like so:

```
filters: {
  genre: "",
  complete: false,
  orderBy: "userRecordCreatedAt",
  orderDirection: "DESC NULLS LAST",
  releaseYearAfter: null,
  releaseYearBefore: null,
  title: "",
};
```

setFilter and applyFilters functions are used to prepare the filters and query the backend

```
setFilter(filterName, filterValue) {
      this.filters[filterName] = filterValue
      this.applyFilters()
    },

applyFilters() {
      LibraryApiService.applyFilters(this.filters)
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data
        })
    },
```

In the UI filter I currently handle things like this:

```
<MenuItem v-for="genre in store.genres">
<a
  class="filter-item-link"
  @click="store.setFilter('genre', genre.name)"
  >
    {{ genre.name }}
  </a>
</MenuItem>
```

This approach feels awkward and error prone to me. For more complex filters like "Movies after 2000", setting the query params directly in the UI starts to get messy. I also want to keep track of which filters are currently active which I might have to track separately in my current setup?

What is the recommended approach for managing complex filter settings and their state in the frontend? Apologies if this is a vague question.